# How to expect object data from a ES6 Class constructor?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I am wanting to accept objects in my constructor but I am not sure how I can do that. Is there a special keyword like `constructor(obj, etc, etc) {}` that can be used? Also, how would I use that date.

As of now I have the basic class setup

```
class Bot {
   constructor() {

   }
}
```

That's all I have right now, literally don't know where to start lol. Did researching but couldn't find answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JavaScript is loosely typed so you need to do nothing more than:

```
class Bot {
    constructor(parameter) {
       this.parameter = parameter;
    }

    doSomething() {
        alert(this.parameter.foo);
    }
}

let instance = new Bot({foo: 'bar'});

instance.doSomething(); // Will fire an alert containing the contents of {foo}
```

Here's a quick example: https://jsfiddle.net/edcs/8qm8sLjp/

Comment: No worries - gotta start somewhere!

Answer (score 1):

As @edcs mentioned, `javascript` doesn't provide a typed mechanism. So what are you planning to do if the passing data is not an `Object`? Throw error?

If so, you can do as following:

```
class Bot {
    constructor(obj) {
       this.validate(obj);
       this.obj = obj;
    }

    validate(obj) {
        if (Object.prototype.toString.call(obj) !== '[object Object]') {
            throw new Error('passing data should be literal object');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet, also what I was looking for.